# How to get the keys and values of a Hashtable which is inside another Hashtable Java?

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a Hashtable named Data keeping the names and addresses (Key, Value) of some clients in a software I am building. But I've another Hashtable named Clients, which keeps some port numbers (generated randomly) and the Data Hashtable (Key, Value). When I'm dealing with the Clients Hashtable, how will I get the Keys and Values of the Data Hashtable?

TIA

Comment: Same way you get the keys and values of any other hashtable?

Answer (score 1):

You get the data in the same way as you do with any other `Hashtable`. You just need to realize that you're now holding another `Hashtable` instance.

Since you did not post any code, I will make an example up with a container of my preference. The same concept applies to any container, including the `Hashtable`.

Consider:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key", "value");
map.get("key"); // returns the value "value" from key "key"
```

Now consider:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapParent = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> mapChild               = new HashMap<>();

mapChild.put("childKey", "childValue");
mapParent.put("child", mapChild);
mapParent.get("child");                  // returns the childMap
mapParent.get("child").get("childKey");  // returns value "childValue"
```

Now you should be able to adapt this to your code. Next time, remember to post what you've tried in your code.